# Dynamic update of string values in tables using Stored procedure

Tags: sql, sql-server

The following is my stored procedure to update a column in SQL SERVER

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[AspPageUpdate] 
     (@type varchar(50),@comp varchar(50),
      @place varchar(50))
AS
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;
    DECLARE @tid varchar;
    DECLARE @ph int;    
    SET @ph = CAST(@place AS int);

    select  @tid = Type_Id 
    from TypeTable 
    where Type_Name = @type 

    UPDATE TypeSetupTable 
    SET PLACE_HOLDERS = @ph 
    WHERE complexity = @comp 
          AND Type_Id = @tid 
END
```

But the table is not getting updated. I think the problem is with Quotes(Strings need to be in quotes, right?).
If i'm giving static values, it is execting, like:

```
UPDATE TypeSetupTable SET PLACE_HOLDERS = @ph WHERE complexity = 'Simple' AND Type_Id = 'SSRS'
```

Please tell me a solution.

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: You are converting string to integer? Did you get any error?

Comment: **Updation?** Where did you learn that word?

Comment: You defined `@tid` as a single-character `varchar` variable. Only the first character you load from `TypeTable` will be stored and uses in the `UPDATE` statement

Comment: Thank You. After giving size to @tid. it works fine..Thanks a lot..

Answer (score 1):

you didn't set the size of the variable `@tid`.

Are you sure of the content of that variable while executing the stored procedure?
Try to put a `raiserror(@tid,15,1)` and check the content of that variable.
[There are blogs](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/09/bad-habits-to-kick-declaring-varchar-without-length) about the habit not to size varchar variables.

It is also [officially documented](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms176089.aspx)  that the size of unsized varchars is 1.